# django request method dynamically

Tags: django, http

I know that request.method will give the type either 'GET' or 'POST' as string and to get any particular parameter we give request.GET.get('parameter') or request.POST.get('parameter')

Now I want to get the GET or POST dictionary dynamically avoiding If conditions.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by this dynamic behavior? If you are using class based views its just one line to get the dictionary. Even with Peter's method it still needs to write in one line.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I am trying to avoid writing if else statement where the parameter remains same in both the methods

Comment: There actually used to be a way of doing this in early versions of Django: `request.REQUEST`. But it was removed because it was confusing and not useful, see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something there's usually any good reason to do, if you're doing the same thing with `GET` and `POST` requests your design is unusual. But it should be possible using `getattr`:

```
query_args = getattr(request, request.method)
```